# How to change contents of a window depending on user input?

Tags: python, tkinter

Lets say that I have a window that looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ATUN.png]

And depending on what the user clicks (Yes or No), without using Toplevel(), change the contents of the same window to this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/keD9k.png]

How would I code this situation? Would I use classes? Or would I use functions that call the new contents?

Code For The Windows:

```
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
label = Label(frame , text='Example/Change')
textbox = Text(frame)
textbox.insert
button1 = Button(frame , text='Yes/Ok')
button2 = Button(frame , text='No/Cancel')

frame.pack()
label.pack( padx=20 , pady=5 )
button1.pack( padx=10 )
button2.pack( padx=10 )
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a callback function to the buttons that changes each button's text like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

toggle_text = {'Yes': 'OK',
               'No': 'Cancel',
               'OK': 'Yes',
               'Cancel': 'No'}

def toggle():
    button1['text'] = toggle_text[button1['text']]
    button2['text'] = toggle_text[button2['text']]

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
label = Label(frame , text='Example')
textbox = Text(frame)
textbox.insert
button1 = Button(frame , text='Yes', command=toggle)
button2 = Button(frame , text='No', command=toggle)

frame.pack()
label.pack( padx=20 , pady=5 )
button1.pack( padx=10 )
button2.pack( padx=10 )
root.mainloop()
```

When a button is clicked, its callback function is called. Inside the callback, the text for each button is changed by looking up a value from the `toggle_text` dictionary.

---

**Edit**

For a simple terms and conditions form, you can do something like the following. This enables/disables a "Continue" button when a check box is clicked/cleared. It also populates the text box (that you already had there) and disables it so that it is not editable.

```
from Tkinter import *

def toggle_continue():
    if accept.get():
        button1.config(state=NORMAL)        # user agrees, enable button
    else:
        button1.config(state=DISABLED)

def cmd_cancel():
    print "User clicked cancel button"

def cmd_continue():
    print "User clicked continue button"


terms_and_conditions = '''Here are our long and unreadable terms and conditions.

We know that you won't read them properly, if at all, so just click the
"I accept" checkbox below, then click the 'Continue' button.'''

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
label = Label(frame , text='Terms and conditions')

textbox = Text(frame)
textbox.insert(INSERT, terms_and_conditions)
textbox.config(padx=15, pady=15, state=DISABLED)

accept = IntVar()
accept_cb = Checkbutton(frame, text="I accept the terms and conditions",
                        variable=accept, command=toggle_continue)

button1 = Button(frame , text='Continue', command=cmd_continue, state=DISABLED)
button2 = Button(frame , text='Cancel', command=cmd_cancel)

frame.pack()
label.pack( padx=20 , pady=5 )
textbox.pack()
accept_cb.pack()
button1.pack( padx=10 )
button2.pack( padx=10 )
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Alright, Thank you, also what if I wanted to add a textbox in the window when the user clicks yes? Kinda like a terms and conditions setup.

Comment: @GabrielAlmodovar : I've added a simple T&C form. I think that you should work on putting it into a class to avoid the use of global variables.